# Send data to a modal

Tags: html, django, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using Django and i'm trying to send data in a modal to get informations of an element.

My button to open the modal is :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#informations">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">{{registration_id}}</span>
</button>
```

And the modal is

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="information">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="{% url 'informations_choices' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="registration" value=......>
                    Get info about : ......
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#information').modal('hide');$('#informations_choices').submit()">
                    Get Info
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal open correctly, but how can transform the "......" into value (by exemple with the {{registration_id}} present in the button ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming here that the modal is on the same page from the beginning. You can just replace the `....` with `{{registration_id}}`. If you want to make the `....` dynamic and changing over the time the person is on the page, you might want to look into javascript frameworks and work with AJAX requests.

If you want to go with plain AJAX you will end up with something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/getnewvalue/",
  data: { array : items_array },
  success: function (data) {     
    // make the changes to the DOM.
  },
  error: function(data) {
      $("#MESSAGE-DIV").html("Something went wrong!");
  }
});
```